# When installing wldc libtinfo.so.5: cannot open shared object file

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, weka

when installing wldc I encounter the following error:

error while loading shared libraries: libtinfo.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to install libtinfo.so.5 - on Ubuntu it's available as

```
apt-get install libtinfo5
```